# Problems with installing Kivy on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, kivy

I tried to install Kivy on my computer but unfortunately I failed. 
I'm running MacOS (v10.13.4) and I have installed Cython successfully (v0.26).
I ran:

```
pip3 install kivy
```

Then the process starts and the following error occurs:

`**Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/yl/kw3svt1x4rdfdjzsd5hds9_c0000gn/T/pip-req-build-869vs3u5/**.`

Is it possible to fix it?

As asked in the comments I'm posting the complete error trace:

```
`**Command Collecting kivy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/49/5c22589099f9b7fd106502ee6634a6675e634d7553fede141a7606e6a92d/Kivy-1.10.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/private/var/folders/yl/kw3svt1x4rdfdjzsd5hds9_c0000gn/T/pip-install-nowxhf43/kivy/setup.py", line 668, in <module>
     base_flags = determine_base_flags()
   File "/private/var/folders/yl/kw3svt1x4rdfdjzsd5hds9_c0000gn/T/pip-install-nowxhf43/kivy/setup.py", line 551, in determine_base_flags
     xcode_dev = getoutput('xcode-select -p').splitlines()[0]
 IndexError: list index out of range
Using distutils

Detected Cython version 0.26
  This version of Cython is untested with Kivy. While this version may
  work perfectly fine, it is possible that you may experience issues. If
  you do have issues, please downgrade to a supported version. It is
  best to use the newest supported version, 0.25.2, but the minimum
  supported version is 0.23.

  If your platform provides a Cython package, check if you can downgrade
  to a supported version. Otherwise, uninstall the platform package and
  install Cython via pip:

    pip install -I Cython==0.25.2
User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
Using this graphics system: OpenGL ES 2
OSX framework used, force to x86_64 only
OSX ARCHFLAGS are: -arch x86_64
GStreamer framework not found, fallback on pkg-config
WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 127)

b'/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found\n'

Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework
Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework
Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework
Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_mixer.framework
SDL2 frameworks not found, fallback on pkg-config
WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 127)

b'/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found\n'

WARNING: A problem occurred while running xcode-select -p (code 2)

b'xcode-select: error: unable to get active developer directory, use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to set one (or see `man xcode-select`)\n'


----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/yl/kw3svt1x4rdfdjzsd5hds9_c0000gn/T/pip-install-nowxhf43/kivy/**`
```

Comment: Post the complete error trace; what you've posted is a generic error message and is not very helpful.